# Store string to char pointer variable

Tags: c

I'm trying to insert a string to a char* pointer but clearly not working.

I read that I may need to use malloc or something? But the other sites don't share them clearly.

```
char* token[1000];
gets(token);
printf("%s\n",*token);
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Now I have to insert the pointer (which points to the string) to a function with the shown parameter.

```
int function(char *token[]);

char token[1000];
gets(token);
char*text=token;
printf("%s\n",text);

function(text);
```

Error of expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

Answer (score 5):

Your variable declaration is wrong, you have declared an array of 1000 character pointers, not 1000 characters. Remove the `*`.

Also never use `gets()`, always use `fgets()` instead since it's safer. There's nothing preventing the user from entering more than 1000 characters with `gets()`, which will overflow the buffer.

Comment: Aditonally then you also have to remove the `*` in teh printf line as then `*token` isn't a string anymore.